# Python 2.7: How to extract article data properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data (title, date and text) from several articles on the same website. Each article has an unique id, so I am using a while loop to iterate through the ids to get each article. The articles' structure is the same.

This is how I am trying to extract the data:

```
# import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# integer for first article id
articleid = 4449
articles = 4459

while articleid < articles:
    # specify the url and article id
    url = 'http://www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?vis=nyheder&id='+str(articleid)
    articleid += 1
    # query the website and return the html to the variable
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    # create CSV file
    csvfile = csv.writer(open('news.csv', 'w'))
    csvfile.writerow(["Title", "Date", "Text"])

    # take out the <div> of name and get its value and text
    title_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'style': 'margin-bottom:0px'})
    title = title_box.text.encode('iso8859-15').strip()
    date_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'font-style:italic; padding-bottom:10px'})
    date = date_box.text.encode('iso8859-15').strip()
    articleText_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'news'})
    articleText = articleText_box.text.encode('iso8859-15').strip()

    # print the data (encoded) to the CSV file
    csvfile.writerow((title, date, articleText))
    print title
    print date
    print articleText
```

So what I am trying to do is to, as mentioned, iterate through all article ids, and put the output in a CSV file. The first article has the id 521 and the last has 4458. When I run this script I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/articleScript.py", line 16, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 421, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 283, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?vis=nyheder&id=4458
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't it open the url, and how is the url type unknown when the last article id is 4458.

This is HTML code from the developer tools
[image]

Comment: You need to tell it to use `http`: `url = 'http://www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?vis=nyheder&id='+str(articleid)`

Comment: Thanks. That led to another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/articleScript.py", line 34, in <module>
    csvfile.writerow(title + date + articleText)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)` Have change the OP script where the encoding is included.

Comment: It looks like you aren't encoding your `date` value.

Comment: Thanks, noticed that. For some reason it doesn't iterate through the while loop. I only get the article with id 4458. Furthermore the text I get out is comma separated i.e. instead writing the whole article every letter in the words is comma separated. For instance, instead of "how" it writes "h,o,w". It should separate title, date and articletext, and not every single word

Comment: Your while loop only contains two lines. `writerows` accepts an iterable and writes each element of that iterable to a cell.  Try `writerow((title, date, articleText))` you should also probably only be opening the file once, I'm pretty sure as written it will write over itself every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ok, now everything should be in the while loop, but I am getting: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/articleScript.py", line 30, in <module>
    articleText = articleText_box.text.encode('iso8859-15').strip()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 1027: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Wrap the line in a `try..except`, catch the error, and print the offending line. Some of your input data has characters that  iso8859-15 doesn't support. Maybe sanitize it or choose another encoding.

Comment: Changed it to UTF-8. However, it still put only one article in the csv file while printing them all in the shell

Comment: When I append, it adds the rest. However, I need it to clear the pre-existing. So that's why I need write mode, which doesn't add all the articles